# What are people using as Login scripts in large enterprises?

Tags: active-directory, login-script

We have recently been tasked with looking after the user login side of things in our enterprise (Windows clients in Active Directory). We have a system at the moment that uses a VBScript login/loggof script to call a couple of DLL written in Visual Basic 6.

The DLL's actions are controled by some configuration files based on users/groups which is administrated from a central application.

This is quite a good system, but we kind of want to come away from Visual Basic 6 for the DLL's (maybe port them to C++, but then you have to make them COM+ to call them from VBScripts, etc.) and possibly away from VBScript for the actual login scripts themselves.

What are other people using, what can people suggest, etc.?

Comment: We're a UNIX shop here ... so, no windows or active directory. We use LDAP for storage and Kerberos for authentication. We are implementing Single-sign on (SSO) these days.

Answer (score 1):

We have a custom logon processor developed in C#.  I certainly would not do this in C++.  You can do unmanaged COM interop calls from C#/.Net.

If the configuration is quite elaborate, you probably would not want to do this in PowerShell either.  PS may be useful for smaller tasks, but it is not suitable once it grows beyond a certain point.

Comment: i did think about doing it in c#/vb.net but i was a bit bothered about the frameworks being installed on all the clients, how do you make sure its installed?

Comment: There is a product called Xenocode (spoon.net) that you can use to package your framework app so that it can run on machines without the framework installed.  Otherwise, you're probably stuck with unmanaged C++.  Yikes.

Comment: @Greg: out of interest, what size is the point at which PowerShell is no longer suitable?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a question of size, but if you are writing a custom command interpreter, it becomes how you unit test, if you want to use DI, all the same questions associated with any other type of application development. Powershell doesn't seem like the best fit for this to me.

Comment: @Zayne: Generally, I would say when a PowerShell script goes over a few hundred lines it can become easier to manage through the development and testing lifecycle/process by using C#.  Aside from size, it's easier and cleaner to do most of this in C#, and there are a wealth of development resources compared to PowerShell.

Comment: Might I ask, what are you doing at login that required the development of something like that?

Comment: Creating a user's environment on citrix/terminal server.  Connecting drives/printers, creating shortcuts, importing application/registry settings.  Based on group memberships or the server environment/silo.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you want/need to achieve with the script? This'll determine how involved it needs to be.

In our setup, our requirement is merely for a few mapped drives on the clients, and a BGInfo on the servers.

For that, we have a couple of WSH VB scripts on netlogon, and call them from GPOs attached to the appropriate OUs (servers OU on server startup, and users OU on user login).

Scripts are maybe 20 lines a piece. Powershell is a logical next-step, but I'm not impressed with it so far. It feels inelegant and clunky.